# Pydantic/SQLAlchemy: How to Avoid cyclic reference error on bidirectional models?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I can't run `model_validate` on my SQLAlchemy ORM because it contains a foreignkey relationship (error at bottom):

Example:

```py
# models.py
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import BaseModel

BaseModel.model_config = {'from_attributes': True}

class Job(BaseModel):
    id: int | None = None
    user: User | None = None


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int | None = None
    jobs: list[Job]
```

SQLAlchemy models:

```py
# db/models.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='jobs')


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Now say you create some users:

```
# main.py
from models import User as UserModel, Job as JobModel
from db.models import User as UserORM, Job as JobORM

session = Session()  # from wherever

# Create users with jobs
db_users = []
db_jobs = []
for _ in range(3):
    db_user = UserModel()
    db_job = JobModel(user=user)
    db_users.append(db_user)
    db_jobs.append(db_job)
session.add_all(db_users)
session.add_all(db_jobs)
session.commit()

# Try to get pydantic models from the existing models
db_user = users[0]
UserModel.model_validate(db_user)
```

The last part of ^ would raise something like

```
   pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Job
   user.jobs.0
     Recursion error - cyclic reference detected [type=recursion_loop, input_value=<Job https://www.codement...pen-requests/iq7j9h5s1j>, input_type=Job]
       For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/recursion_loop
```

But there seems to be no way around it! How on earth convert the data back to Pydantic models when it throws an error on `model_validate`?